# Is it possible to communicate between two android telephones through a USB hub?

Tags: android, usb

I have the following:

Two Android devices connected to a USB-hub with its own power supply that supplies power to the two Android devices. The hub is also connected to my computer and both of them can be found by the Android Debug Bridge (adb).

Is it possible to communicate between the two devices over the USB-hub while receiving power through the hub?

I have read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/ but it is not clear to me if two Android devices can communicate over USB or if it is only possible to communicate with specific peripherals over the interface. Do I need a special OTG cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the electonics and security behind the usb-HUB it is not possible to make two devices communicate directly. Now you have two ways: the difficult one is to do sone tricks with your pc in order to make a virtual bridge between you two devices, the simplier one is to make sure that at least one of your phones has OTG and then connect 'em via an OTG cable ( you can craft yourself one if you don't want to spend money, check on the internet, it is an amazing place ;-)

Comment: I decided to go for communication via Bluetooth instead, I have a lot more programming experience with wireless. Thanks for you response.